# How to modify a value (integer) in a text file?

Tags: python, file, text

My code can only update the `Inventory.txt` when all the values inside are single digit. When the inventory text file contains 2 digits, it starts to mess up. How do I fix this?
[Inventory text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lS6F.png)
[Codes for product text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ormU.png)

```
import os
#empty list to append data
codes=[]
inventories=[]
#opening code text file (read) in module
code= open("Code.txt","r")
for line in code:
    line1=line.rstrip()
    line1=int(line1)
    codes.append(line1)

#opening inventory text file (read) in module
Inventory=open("Inventory.txt","r+")
for line in Inventory:
    line1=line.rstrip()
    line1=int(line1)
    inventories.append(line1)
#a=codes
#b=inventories
def inventory_update(a,b):
    while True:
        global cs1
        cs1= int(input("Enter the item's code:"))
        if cs1 in a:
            for x in range(0,len(a)):
                if cs1==a[x]:
                    print("Stock:",b[x])
                    while True:
                        ar=input("Add/Remove/Done(a/r/d):")
                        ar=ar.lower()
                        if ar=="a":
                            add=int(input("How many to add?:"))
                            b[x] += add
                            print("Stock:",b[x])
                        elif ar=="r":
                            remove=int(input("How many to remove?:"))
                            b[x] -= remove
                            print("Stock:",b[x])
                        elif ar=="d":
                            print(cs1,":",b[x])
                            Inventory.seek(x+x,os.SEEK_SET)  
                            Inventory.write(str(b[x]))
                            Inventory.seek(0,os.SEEK_SET)
                            Inventory.close()
                            break                          
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid code")
inventory_update(codes,inventories)
```

Comment: Updating a file in place only works if the replacement is the same length as the original value. Don't try to do that with a text file. You should update the `inventories` array and then rewrite the entire file.

Comment: Have a look also at the line "Inventory.seek (x+x,os.SEEK_SET)". The position you try to write at is not correct (x+x). This is only correct for single digit inventories...